# JAVA lo4j Correct Exception handling and logging

Tags: java, logging, exception, log4j

For some reason I am missing part of the stack trace, the actual root of the exception.

```
public void method1(){

   try{
     method2();
   }
     catch(SearchException e){
     logger.error("Search error", e.getMessage(), e);
   }
 }

 private void method2(){
   try{
   //Logic which potentially can throw exception
   ....
   ....
   }
   catch(Exception e){
   throw new SearchException("Error during execution Module A", e); 
  }
}


public class SearchException extends Exception{


    public SearchException(String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }
}
```

Anyone knows a reason why I am missing part of stacktrace where fist place exception happened? Could you suggest a correct way of handling/logging exceptions?

Comment: Post your `SearchException` class

Comment: @SubhrajyotiMajumder SearchExceptionClass added.

Answer (score 1):

```
super(message, cause);
```

The `message` will be the `detailMessage` of `Throwable` class. And it will be used in `toString` method and source cause(Exception) will be ignored.

```
358    public String toString() {
359        String s = getClass().getName();// class Name
360        String message = getLocalizedMessage();// detailMessage
361        return (message != null) ? (s + ": " + message) : s;
362    }
```

You may override the toString method in custom `Exception` class.

```
class SearchException extends Exception{
    String str=null;
    public SearchException(String str,Throwable th){

        super( th);
        this.str=str;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return super.toString() +" - "+ str;
    }
}
```

This customized form will print -

> Search error
>   -----java.lang.NullPointerException-------SearchException: java.lang.NullPointerException - Error during execution Module A